# ¿Por qué no me incluye edades mayores a 25 años?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

tengo una función para sacar la edad más repetida en un arreglo de usuarios, todo funciona correctamente hasta la edad de 25. Al momento de hacer el código, lo hice con los 4 primeros objetos del arreglo, después quise verificar si era totalmente funcional, y al agregar más objetos y colocarle edades a partir del 26, no lo toma en cuenta y me sigue devolviendo 23, pero si pongo otros 2 objetos con 25, me retorna ese 25

```js
 let students = [
            { name: "Daniela", age: 25 },
            { name: "Andrea", age: 23 },
            { name: "José", age: 27 },
            { name: "Samuel", age: 23 },
            { name: "Samuel", age: 28 },
            { name: "Samuel", age: 24 },
            { name: "Samuel", age: 26},
            { name: "Samuel", age: 26},
            { name: "Samuel", age: 26},
        ];
        
          function findMostCommonAge(students) {
            let ObjAges = {}
            
            for(const student of students){
              ObjAges[student.age] = ObjAges[student.age] + 1 || 1
            }
            
            let MostCommon = 0
            
            for(const key in ObjAges){
              if(ObjAges[key] > MostCommon)
                MostCommon = key
            }
              
            return MostCommon
          }
          
        console.log(findMostCommonAge(students));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en la comparación:

```
ObjAges[key] > MostCommon
```

Se está comparando el valor de las veces que aparece el elemento `ObjAges[key]` contra el valor de la clave `MostCommon`.

Se puede solucinar así, en comentarios están los pasos para corregirlo:

```js
let students = [
  { name: "Daniela", age: 25 },
  { name: "Andrea", age: 23 },
  { name: "José", age: 27 },
  { name: "Samuel", age: 23 },
  { name: "Samuel", age: 28 },
  { name: "Samuel", age: 24 },
  { name: "Samuel", age: 26 },
  { name: "Samuel", age: 26 },
  { name: "Samuel", age: 26 },
];

function findMostCommonAge(students) {
  let ObjAges = {}

  for (const student of students) {
    ObjAges[student.age] = ObjAges[student.age] + 1 || 1
  }

  // 1. inicializar con el primer elemento del arreglo
  let MostCommon = students[0].age

  for (const key in ObjAges) {
    // 2. Comparar los valores obtenidos de la key actual y la key anterior
    if (ObjAges[key] > ObjAges[MostCommon])
      MostCommon = key
  }

  return MostCommon
}

console.log(findMostCommonAge(students));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Me estaban dando otra opción con crear una variable en 0, y si ObjAges[key] era mayor, se asigna esa key a la variable creada, y otra en null para agregarle la key más repetida, pero esta me parece más fácil de entender